# Solving $7 = 8 - 2e^{-3k}$

Tags: logarithms

So, this is an assignment my friend and I have for our homework:
$7 = 8 - 2e^{-3k}$

And the solution should be:
$\frac{1}{3\ln(2)}$

But, I have no idea how they got there. I tried doing:

$$\begin{align*}
7 &= 8 - 2e^{-3k}\\
1 &= 2e^{-3k}\\
\frac{1}{2} &= e^{-3k}
\end{align*}$$

And now I don't know what to do next. Help!

PS: Neither of us was in school when they were learning this lesson. So, some description along the way will be greatly welcomed!

Comment: From your last equation: remember that $\ln\,e^u=u$... Also, $\ln\frac1{s}=-\ln\,s$.

Comment: Take reciprocals: $e^{3k} = 2$. Take logs: $3k = \ln 2$. Solve for $k$.

Comment: (You should probably review what a logarithm is and its basic properties.)

Comment: But this does not lead to the specified conclusion. Perhaps there was an error copying the assignment and/or solution?

Comment: Yes, thought if you are sure this is the correct question, then you copied the answer wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\frac12 & = e^{-3k} \\  \\
2 & = e^{3k} \\  \\
\log_e 2 & = 3k \\  \\
\frac{\log_e 2}{3} & = k
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Oh, we were getting that answer, too. I guess she copied down the wrong solution or something. Haha. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The logarithm of a positive real number $x$ with respect to the base $a \in (0,\infty)\setminus \{1\}$ is the unique real number $\log_a x$ with the property that $a^{\log_a x}=x$.

In your case you have $\frac{1}{2}=e^{-3k}$ which is equivalent to $e^{3k}=2$. $\ln$ is the notation for $\log_e$ so by the definition in the first paragraph $3k=\ln e^{3k}=\ln 2$.